# How to upload image to amazon aws S3 using presigned Url

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3, axios

Hi I am getting 400 bad request error when I try to upload an image to my amazon aws bucket using an presigned url from my vue app. I have successfully generated a presigned url but I am unable to post an image to my bucket using it.

Route to get presigned url

```
const express = require('express')
const router = new express.Router()
const requireAuth = require('../middleware/requireAuth')

router.use(requireAuth)

const v4 = require('uuid')

const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    region: process.env.BUCKET_REGION,
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
})

router.get('/upload', async (req, res) => {
    const key = `${req.user._id}/${v4()}.jpeg`

    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
        Bucket: 'my-post-app-bucket',
        ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
        Key: key
    }, (err, url) => res.send({ key, url }))
})

module.exports = router
```

Vue client

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
    <input type="file" @change="handleChange">
    <button>add</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      file: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleChange(e){
      this.file = e.target.files[0]
    },
    async handleSubmit(){
      await this.$store.dispatch('images/uploadImage', this.file)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Vuex action posting to presigned url

```
actions: {
    async uploadImage(context, file){
      try {
        const res = await api.get('/upload', {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
          }
        })
        await axios.put(res.data.url, file, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': file.type
          }
        })
      }catch(err){
        console.log(err.message)
        context.commit('SET_ERROR', err.message, { root: true })
      }
    }
  }
```

Aws CORS permission

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://localhost:8080"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

I am getting "Request failed with status code 400" error.

Comment: What's the response body?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar scenario some weeks ago, here's how I solved

```
const formData = new FormData();
Object.entries(fields).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    formData.append(key, value);
});

formData.append('file', file.originFileObj);

axios.post(url, formData, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
})
```

`fields` comes from the call to [generate_presigned_post](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_post)

`file` is an object from type `File`